# How do I call multiple web services in one project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a login application. Most of data is generated using a web service. I've created a  window based app. I would like to implement the rest of my project by placing all of my code in the `AppDelegate`.

I already have one web service running and now I would like to add another service in my `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear, but there is absolutely nothing stopping you from making multiple `NSURLConnection`s to the web service(s) in question. I mean, for example if you are using `SBJSON` why not:

```
NSString *jsonOne = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestOne returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *jsonTwo = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestTwo returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSDictionary *wsDictOne = [self.jsonParser objectWithString:jsonOne error:NULL];
NSDictionary *wsDictTwo = [self.jsonParser objectWithString:jsonTwo error:NULL];
```

I think you need to expand your question, but no, there is nothing stopping you from calling all the web services you would like.

Comment: Note that in a production app you should probably never use any synchronous requests because they block the main thread, hanging/freezing your app until it completes or fails. The "watchdog" process on iOS will kill your app if you block the main thread for too long. Regardless, synchronous requests are simpler to implement than asynchronous requests and therefore are useful for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Yes, Jack L is right. I just used the synchronous requests for demo purposes.